# Find values in two different arrays and combine them to save in dtb

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have these two nested arrays:

First array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 200 
    [1] => OK. Created. 
    [2] => Array 
    ( [order] => 42c8dd9265f287693048353d6c95058f
        [shipments] => Array ( 
            [0] => IZ0716B9F2FA 
            [1] => IZ07FBD4F8E7 
            [2] => IZ075453B538 
            [3] => IZ07647393B4 
            [4] => IZ073EE209CB 
            [5] => IZ07CFFA8D8C 
            [6] => IZ0720BB9BB4 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Second array:

```
 Array (
     [0] => CZK 
     [1] => invoice 
     [2] => Array( 
     [0] => Array ( 
        [reference] => 1710039172 
        [pickup_date] => 2017-12-12 
        [type] => regular 
        [from] => Array([id] => 53420 ) 
        [to] => Array([name] => [surname] => XXX 
            [company] => 
            [street] => XXX 
            [city] => XXX 
            [zip] => 27343 
            [country] => XX 
            [phone] => XXX 
            [email] => XXX ) 
        [packages] => Array( 
            [0] => Array( 
                [weight] => 1 
                [width] => 10 
                [height] => 20 
                [length] => 30 
                ) 
        ) ) 
    [1] => Array( 
    [reference] => 1710049181 
    [pickup_date] => 2017-12-12... etc.
```

Order of items in arrays is the same ( I can address item 0 to item 0 in second array ).

And I need to combine values of reference with shipments no's - my aim is to store reference numbers with shipment numbers in one row in database. Any advice is welcome :)

Comment: Advice: use `foreach` to merge two arrays to single new array.

Comment: post the final result

Comment: On the end it should look like following:

INSERT INTO shipments (id_shipment, id_order) VALUES (shipment,reference)...for example:
INSERT INTO shipments (id_shipment, id_order) VALUES (IZ0716B9F2FA,1710039172 )